# Writing selected text from a file to txt file using C

Tags: c

prefacing by saying, I've lurked in Stackoverflow and this is my first Question, but thank you all you kind souls for your contributions!
I am trying to write comments and classes from a .java file to a .txt file using C programming. I used the fgetc and fputc functions to do this and managed to write the whole file across, but when I try to communicate that I only want the comments right up to the class (so before the "{" and everything after the "}") it seems to not print anything. I am quite new to C and just a bit stuck. I have included my code below, any help would be super appreciated. Sorry if this is hard to understand, I am not natively English speaking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *input = fopen("text.java", "r"); //opens file
    FILE *comments = fopen("comments.txt", "w");
    char ch;

    ch = fgetc(input);
    while(ch != EOF)
    {
        while(!strcmp(ch, "{"))
        {
            fputc(ch, comments);
            
            ch = fgetc(input);
        }
        ch = fgetc(input);
    }
    
    fclose(input);
    fclose(comments);
    
    return 0;
        
}
```

Comment: Since `ch` is of type char, it will never equal EOF.  You must declare `int ch`

Comment: `strcmp` expects the first argument to be `char *`.  You should get a compiler warning on `strcmp(ch, "{")`.  You should use `ch == '{'` to decide if `{` was read.

Comment: Note that your current logic is flawed.  If you get an EOF while scanning for a `{`, your inner loop will never terminate.  The standard idiom of `while( ( c = fgetc ) != EOF )` helps prevent this error.  Any time you read from the stream, you should be prepared for EOF and handle it appropriately.

Comment: @WilliamPursell so when I don't include the while(!strcmp(ch, "{")) loop it all runs fine and prints the whole file across and stops at the end of the file, so it's recognizing the EOF. It is just when i try to tell it to not copy { and the contents within that it stops reading it. I tried putting in the changed you suggest but it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: But i understand the 3rd comment and have implemented that change, thank you.

Comment: Is my understanding correct that you want to write everything up to the `{` character, but nothing afterwards? Or do you want to continue writing again as soon as a closing `}` is encountered?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel so I would like to write everything up to a { and then continue writing after a } .

Comment: @PhilMorrison: In your question, you did not mention that you wanted to continue writing after an `}`. Please [edit] your question to include this important information. It should not be necessary for someone to read the entire comments section to understand your question.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel sorry not sure how to reply in this, thank you for your answer and sorry for not including the second part, I will edit that right away. Your answer gave me a lot of direction and allowed me to understand where my logic was going wrong. From you and William, i've managed to adapt it to make it work. The boolean looks most effective but I went with flags as that is what my workbook wanted me to use for this but I imagine a boolean would be better for it. Thank you again for the help and for the time you took to answer, I really appreciate it. Sorry for the late response!

Comment: @PhilMorrison: A flag variable and a boolean variable are essentially the same thing, as both can be either true or false, i.e. nonzero or zero. I prefer to use the `bool` data type, because then it is apparent at first glance that the variable is only supposed to have two states, whereas if you instead implement the flag variable as an `int`, this is not so easily apparent.

Comment: @PhilMorrison: However, as stated in my answer, if you only use a flag/boolean variable, your program will only work if you have a single nesting level of braces. For example, your program will start writing again as soon as it sees a `}`, even if there were two `{` beforehand and only one of them was closed. See my answer for a solution which can also handle multiple nesting levels.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel interesting about the bool, after changing it to flag it did look less truncated and a bit harder to follow. I have accepted the answer, I did vote on it but I don't have 15 points yet! Again thank you and I hope to be able to help someone as you did me soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments section by someone else, your code has the following errors:

1. The return type of `fgetc` is `int`, not `char`. The value `EOF` cannot be represented in `char`, so you should not truncate the `int` return value to `char`. Instead, you should declare `ch` as an `int`.
2. The function `strcmp` is for comparing strings, not characters.
3. When calling `fgetc` in your inner loop, you are not checking the return value for `EOF`.

Also, your algorithm for solving the problem does not seem correct.

One way to solve the problem is for your program to always remember whether it is inside a brace or not, and to act accordingly. For example, you can declare a `bool inside_brace` variable which always specifies whether you are inside a brace or not, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//the following line is necessary for the "bool" data type
#include <stdbool.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    FILE *input = fopen("text.java", "r");
    FILE *comments = fopen("comments.txt", "w");

    int ch;
    bool inside_brace = false;

    while ( ( ch = fgetc(input) ) != EOF )
    {
        if ( !inside_brace )
        {
            if ( ch == '{' )
            {
                inside_brace = true;
                continue;
            }

            fputc( ch, comments );
        }
        else //inside a brace
        {
            if ( ch == '}' )
            {
                inside_brace = false;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(input);
    fclose(comments);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;       
}
```

Note that this solution will only work if you only have one nesting level of braces, i.e. that you don't have one `{` inside another `{` without first closing the first `{` with a `}`. If it is possible that you have more than one level of nesting, then the variable `bool inside_brace` will not be sufficient. Instead, you will need a counter to keep track of the current nesting level, for example like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    FILE *input = fopen("text.java", "r");
    FILE *comments = fopen("comments.txt", "w");

    int ch;
    int nesting_level = 0;

    while ( ( ch = fgetc(input) ) != EOF )
    {
        switch ( ch )
        {
        case '{':
            nesting_level++;
            continue;
        case '}':
            nesting_level--;
            if ( nesting_level < 0 )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "Error: Negative nesting level encountered!\n" );
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            continue;
        }

        if ( nesting_level == 0 )
            fputc( ch, comments );
        }
    }

    fclose(input);
    fclose(comments);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;       
}
```